# Shadertoy: How to mix-add-multiply any two shaders?

Tags: gpu, shader, webgl

Are there any crafty tricks to mix two shaders together? i.e. to add the shaders together, else to render one shader in a central square and another as a frame? Can we rename some of the input-output parameters and add them in a final image mix meta-function?

i.e. If i change

```
void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{...}
```

changed to:

```
void mainImage( out vec4 A_FragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{...}
```

and

```
void mainImage( out vec4 B_FragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{...}
```

Perhaps I can mix and lerp the shaders A and B from left to right of the canvas?

Comment: If my answer was ok for you, please accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the render to texture enabled by Shadertoy buffer tabs and iChannel mapping.

To do it, just add a BufA tab and put your first shader code into it, then do the same with BufB tab and your second shader code.

For example I will generate two gradient images and sum them. BufA will draw some red to black, and BufB will draw some black to green gradient.

```
// Shader in buffer A returns a red to black gradient
void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
    vec2 uv = fragCoord / iResolution.xy;
    fragColor = vec4(uv.x, 0., 0., 1.);
}
```

```
// Shader in buffer B returns a black to green gradient
void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
    vec2 uv = fragCoord / iResolution.xy;
    fragColor = vec4(0., 1. - uv.x, 0., 1.);
}
```

Enable iChannel0 and iChannel1 in the bottom panel and connect them to BufA and BufB. At this point ShaderToy will render both shaders into iChannel textures, before Image tab main shader is called.

In the Image tab, you can retrieve the textures by accessing iChannel[i] you mapped, and use iChannelResolution[i] to compute uv coordinates.

And you can mix everything the way you want

```
void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
    // Normalized pixel coordinates (from 0 to 1)
    vec2 uvA = fragCoord / iChannelResolution[0].xy;
    vec2 uvB = fragCoord / iChannelResolution[1].xy;

    // Output to screen
    // Fragment is the sum of both gradients: red to green
    fragColor = texture(iChannel0, uvA) + texture(iChannel1, uvB);
}
```

The whole thing should look like this

[image]

Comment: Hey Thanks! that answer is Awesome I have followed it as a guide and I haven't managed to add pre-written shaders for the moment. Specifically, I wished to know, can add/multiply any short shadertoys into superimposed new version by renaming some of the variables... i.e. https://www.shadertoy.com/view/ltd3R7 and https://www.shadertoy.com/view/wdVSR3... Can I copy-pase these pages into new buffers and see the cube through the fluid? Sorry I didn't reply, I became confused about the application of your code to remix other people's codes.

Comment: Great if it helps you. Could you btw accept the answer? For your second question, did you give it a try?

Comment: Thanks! I have managed a basic first attempt, cool advice thanks. shadertoy.com/view/tsXfz2

Comment: Awesome! Shader mixing could be very fun!!